# In R shiny is there a way to freeze the x-axis on an interactive plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on creating an interactive line graph using `ggplot` in R shiny. The way I am doing it is having the user in the UI select the values they want to see in the plot using a picker input. In the server the data is then filtered based on the selection from the user. I specified the x axis in `ggplot` using `scale_x_continuous`. I set a sequence to be 0 through 24 with breaks by 1. However when a user would select, say 1-10, the x-axis would change to only show 1-10.

I want the x-axis to remain 0 through 24 no matter what the user selects. Is there a way to do that? Would the solution be in specifying the `ggplot` x-axis limits in a different way limits or in how I am using the picker input to filter the data?

Thanks!

Here is my code if it helps:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Create sample dataset and name bin
set.seed(1234) 
hour <- sample(1:24, size=100, replace=TRUE)
calls <- sample(1:55, size=100, replace =TRUE)
mydata <- data.frame(hour,calls)
name <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarize(n())

name_bin <- as.data.frame(name$hour)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1 ("R shiny ggplot Question"),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "myPicker",
    label = "Select Hour in the day",  
    choices = name_bin, 
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE,
      size = 10, 
      `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),
    multiple = TRUE),
  box(
    width = 11,
    plotOutput("graph1"))
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

  g1 <- dplyr::filter(mydata,hour %in% input$myPicker) 

  g2 <- g1 %>% 
    group_by(hour) %>% 
    summarize(number = n())

  ggplot(g2, aes(x=hour, y=number)) + 
    geom_line(color = 'darkblue') + geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24, by=1)) +  ###### Better way to set x-limits?
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, max(g2$number), by=5))+ 
    theme_minimal()+
    labs(y="Number of Calls", x="Hour in the day",title = "")
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to set the limits on your axis: you were almost there!

The call to `scale_x_continuous` in your `renderPlot()` function only sets the breaks in the axis (kind of how it's labeled).  You want to set the limits, and you can do that within the `scale_x_continuous` function via the argument `limits=`.  [See the documentation for more information](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html), but this should work for you:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24, by=1), limits = c(0,24))
```

Alternatively, if you just want to set the limits, but the default "breaks" in the axis are fine, you can access x and y limits more easily using `xlim(0,24)` in place of `scale_x_continuous`.

Use caution though: setting limits of the axis will result in *dropping that data* - meaning it won't be used in any further stat functions.  If you still need to keep that data for other stat functions within the plot, you can use `coord_cartesian()` (see [the documentation here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html)).

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! Also the caution message and links to the documentation in your answer were greatly appreciated!